# Spiral Matrix that show the current position after we input the no of shiftings

Tags: c#

my program is

```cs
using System;

namespace MatrixCount
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Number Of Rows and colums!");
            int Row = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int Colum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Number of shiftings!");
            int shift = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            int TotalCells = Row * Colum;
              string direction = "right";     //Assigining initigal direction is right//
            int[,] matrix = new int[Row,Colum];
            int value1=1;        //For the coOrdinate(1,2) value2=2 and value1=1//
            int value2=1;
             bool Flag = true;          


            if (shift > TotalCells)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid shiftings!"); 
            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= shift; i++)
                {
                    if (direction == "right" && (i > Colum))
                    {
                        direction = "down";
                        value1++;
                    }
                    if (direction == "down" && (Row <i))
                    {
                        direction = "left";

                          value2--;
                    }
                    if (direction == "left" && (Colum < 1))
                    {
                        direction = "up";

                        value1--;
                    }
                    if (direction == "up" && (Row ==1))
                    {
                        direction = "right";

                        Colum--;
                        Colum--;
                        Row--;
                        Row--;

                    }


                    if (direction == "right" && Flag == false) 
                    {

                        value2++;
                    }
                    if (direction == "down")
                    {
                        value1++;
                    }
                    if (direction == "left")
                    {
                        value2--;
                    }
                    if (direction == "up")
                    {
                        value1--;
                    }
                    if (direction == "right")
                    {
                        Flag = false;
                    }
                }


                    }
            Console.Write((value1, value2));            

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understand the objective correctly, something like this mayhaps?

```cs
using System;

namespace MatrixCount
{
    class Program
    {
        enum Directions { Right, Up, Left, Down }

        static void Main()
        {
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter Number Of Rows and Colums!");
                uint Rows = uint.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                uint Colums = uint.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                uint TotalCells = Rows * Colums;

                uint Shifts;
                bool InvalidInput;
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Number of Shiftings!");
                    Shifts = uint.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    InvalidInput = Shifts > TotalCells;
                    if (InvalidInput)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid shiftings!");
                    }
                } while (InvalidInput);

                Directions Direction = Directions.Right;
                int R = 0;
                int C = 0;

                uint BoundaryLeft = 0;
                uint BoundaryBottom = Rows - 1;
                uint BoundaryRight = Colums - 1;
                uint BoundaryTop = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < Shifts; i++)
                {
                    bool Shifted = false;
                    while (!Shifted)
                    {
                        switch (Direction)
                        {
                            case Directions.Right:
                                if (C + 1 > BoundaryRight)
                                    Direction = Directions.Down;
                                else
                                {
                                    C++;
                                    Shifted = true;
                                }
                                break;
                            case Directions.Down:
                                if (R + 1 > BoundaryBottom)
                                    Direction = Directions.Left;
                                else
                                {
                                    R++;
                                    Shifted = true;
                                }
                                break;
                            case Directions.Left:
                                if (C - 1 < BoundaryLeft)
                                    Direction = Directions.Up;
                                else
                                {
                                    C--;
                                    Shifted = true;
                                }
                                break;
                            case Directions.Up:
                                if (R - 2 < BoundaryTop)
                                {
                                    Direction = Directions.Right;

                                    BoundaryLeft++;
                                    BoundaryBottom--;
                                    BoundaryRight--;
                                    BoundaryTop++;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    R--;
                                    Shifted = true;
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("You end up at ({0}, {1})!", R, C);// add 1 to r and c if you  want to be a mathematician
                Console.WriteLine("Again?");
            }
            while (Console.ReadLine().ToUpper() == "YES");
        }
    }
}
```